# Cross-browser styling scrollbars

Tags: css, scrollbar, scrollbars

I know this is [possible](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/css_scrollbar_color_code.php3) in [IE and Opera](http://htmlbook.ru/css/scrollbar-base-color).

And what can be done to add style to scrollbar in Chrome and Firefox?

(I need to style `overflow:scroll`, not browser scrollbars)

I know this can be done via [jquery](http://www.rshahin.com/jquery-plugin-to-style-scrollbars-cross-browser-compatible/).

So should I desperately use JavaScript after detecting FF or Chrome?

Comment: You can't style `overflow: scroll` - it just tells the browser that scroll bars should be displayed on overflow...

Comment: I wanted to say that I want to style scrollbars that appear in the `DIV` when `overflow: scroll` applied, and not browser window scrollbars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Check out JScrollbar](http://www.myjqueryplugins.com/jScrollbar/demo)